# Calculate days to the next holiday day

Tags: python

I want to calculate the number of days to the next holiday (e.g., Christmas). For instance, if the input is `2019-12-01` then the answer would be `24 days` as shown below:

```
import datetime
START_DATE = '2019-12-01'
startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(START_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d')
XMAS_2019 = '2019-12-25'
xmas2019 = datetime.datetime.strptime(XMAS_2019, '%Y-%m-%d')
(xmas2019-startdate).days
# 24
```

I want a solution that does not require specifying the year in the holiday date. For instance, if the input is `2018-12-01` or `2016-12-01`, I should not have to manually define `xmas2018` or `xmas2016` and calculate the difference in days. Assume that `input_date` is a proper `datetime` variable

```
def days_to_xmas(input_date):
    ...
    ans = (input_date - ...).days
    return ans
```

Comment: You actually have two problems here - choosing the holiday after and closest to your given date, and determining the difference. Getting the difference is the easy part.

Comment: Yes, you're right...are you suggesting I modify something in my post?

Comment: You can hardcore the month and day of each holiday and set the variable to take the actual year and if that day is lower than today (the same variable which you are using to slice only the year) then add 1 yes to the date. For instance 4th of July gets hardcoded day 4 and month 7. Current date is 30-01-2019 therefore, 04-07-2019. Since it's lower than today you add an extra year, hence 04-07-2020

Comment: Do you want something like `if startdate.month > xmas.month or (startdate.month == xmas.month and startdate.day > xmas.day): xmas.year = startdate.year + 1 else: xmas.year = startdate.year`?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything, except that maybe you could have broken this into two different questions. It might have helped to define the first part better, for instance I assume you care about a lot more holidays than just Christmas but your question isn't clear about that.

Comment: You might want to look into using pandas Calendar functions https://towardsdatascience.com/holiday-calendars-with-pandas-9c01f1ee5fee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use auxiliary function to compute Christmas based upon your input. Based on the feedback provided by @MarkRansom:

```py
import datetime
def get_christmas(date):
    """Returns the date of the Christmas of the year of the date"""
    next_xmas = datetime.datetime(date.year, 12, 25)
    if next_xmas < date:
        next_xmas = datetime.datetime(date.year+1, 12, 25)
    return next_xmas
```

Then use the function you are defining:

```
def days_to_xmas(input_date):
    if type(input_date) is str:
        startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    else:
        startdate = input_date
    ans = (get_christmas(startdate) - startdate).days
    return ans
```

The following function is simplified assuming that `input_date` is a `datetime` variable

```
def days_to_xmas(input_date):
    ans = (get_christmas(input_date) - input_date).days
    return ans
```

Some examples to validate

```
days_to_xmas(datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-12-01', '%Y-%m-%d'))
# 24
days_to_xmas(datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-12-26', '%Y-%m-%d'))
# 364
```

Comment: You're doing `get_christmas` the hard way. It could be simply `return datetime.datetime(date.year, 12, 25)`.

Comment: The answer is still incomplete though, because it only works for a single holiday and returns a negative number if the date is after the holiday.

Comment: I think your answer is mixing `datetime` variables with `string` variables...not working as is when I input a `datetime` variable...trying to edit on my own

Comment: @MarkRansom, I agree, but I don't know what to do in that case.

Comment: @CPak, I updated my answer. Now, it will work for str and datetime.

Comment: Thanks - your answer was the most helpful. A comment by `Celius` deals with the issue brought up by @MarkRansom - what happens when the date occurs in the same year but after the date of the holiday. I've suggested an edit for your answer.

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf I hope you don't mind the edits - thanks again for your help.